# EE Freemember register with multi lang?

Tags: freemember, transcribe

I'm having some trouble using FreeMember and Transcribe. It seems like the member register posts the action to the site url.

However, if the site url includes a language prefix the page seems to just refresh, doesn't register a new member and doesn't return to the allocated return page.

eg.. www.site.com/form/fr/ will fail. With transcribe (language prefix) disabled it does work.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Freemember forms simply post to the current URL, with an `ACT` parameter which tells EE which action to perform. I doubt Transcribe itself is interfering too much with this process.

I'd be willing to bet though that you have some sort of htaccess rule or extension which is redirecting the form submission to a different URL, and in the process losing the POST data.

You can check this by looking at the Chrome/Firebug network tab and checking what response the POST request gets.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have in fact got it working by enabling PHP on the page. But its strange because I have the same problem; but now with ee search. Its returning a 301 error when following your suggestion in chrome. Whats throwing me is the fact when Transcribe is removed the problem is resolved.